# Pushing data into a select based on the input of another select

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to push values into the breed drop down based on the input selected in the first select. I have the all the data needed. I just don't know how to push it into the select. The data is accessed by breed_data.dog, breed_data.cat and so on. So initially I made an each loop inside of the change function. I don't know where to begin, any tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
   <form id="filter" class="filter" action="http://dev/petlist/public/site/index" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">  
       <select name="petsDropDown" id="form_petsDropDown">
         <option value="allPets">All Pets</option>
         <option value="barnyard">Barnyard</option>
         <option value="bird">Bird</option>
         <option value="cat">Cats</option>
         <option value="dog">Dogs</option>
         <option value="horse">Horse</option>
         <option value="pig">Pigs</option>
         <option value="smallfurry">Smallfurry</option>
      </select>          
      <select name="breedDropDown" id="form_breedDropDown">
         <option value="select_breed">Select Breed</option>
      </select>        
   </form>


   $(function(){
      $('#form_petsDropDown').change(function(){
         $('#form_breedDropDown').prop('disabled',($(this).val()=='allPets'));
         $(breed_data).each(function() { 
            /*console.log(breed_data.dog);
              console.log(breed_data.cat);
              console.log(breed_data.smallfurry);
              console.log(breed_data.bird);
              console.log(breed_data.pig);
              console.log(breed_data.horse);*/
         });
      }).change();
   });
```

Comment: What's `breed_data`, an object? Can you add it to your question?

Comment: breed_data is called from another js file. It's an array of dogs,cat,and all the other animals.

Comment: Here's a js fiddle so you can get an idea of what I'm trying to do. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2yWeN/6/

Comment: You probably don't want to put the code that pushes the breeds onto your select menu in the change event of the pets menu since that would change it every time the pets menu changed. You probably only want to do it once, before the change event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#form_petsDropDown').change(function(){
     $('#form_breedDropDown').prop('disabled',(this.value === 'allPets'));

     var options = $([]),
         data    = this.value in breed_data ? breed_data[this.value] : [];

     $.each(data, function(k,v) {
          var opt = $('<option />', {text: v, value: v});
          options = options.add(opt)
     });

     $('#form_breedDropDown').html(options);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#form_petsDropDown').change(function(){
  var breed = $(this).val(), // get current pet
      breeds = breed in breed_data // get breeds based on pet
          ? breed_data[breed] // load matches
          : {'select_breed':'Select Breed'}; // default when none are found
      $breeds = $('#form_breedDropDown'); // alias

  // disable when necessary
  $breeds.prop('disabled', !(breed in breed_data)).empty();

  // populate results
  $.each(breeds, function(v,k){
      $('<option>',{'value':v}).text(k).appendTo($breeds);
  });
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fnd2C/1/)

- Shows breeds (when available)
- Enables breed drop-down (when breeds found)
- Shows "Select Breed" when "allBreeds" or no matching breed is found.

Comment: For some reason this through an error when I tired it, thanks for looking though,    cheers

Comment: @user2677350: yea, typo'd it and was working on it. here's final result: http://jsfiddle.net/fnd2C/